# Блокировки в бд ms sql

Tags: sql-server

Блокировки на обновлении при чтении таблицы и блокировки на чтение при обновлении таблицы в бд `ms sql`.

Comment: Даа случаются иногда...

Answer (score 2):

1. Завершайте транзакции явным COMMIT.
2. Ставьте на выборки хинт with (NOLOCK).
3. Ясно выражайте свои мысли.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите в сторону TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL.